# How to split a module over multiple files in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have a module, which holds all the classes that make up an API wrapper. Here's the module's structure:

(file: zway.rb)

```
module Zway
  class API
  # instantiates API object
  end

  class Main
  # holds top level functions
  end

  class Controller
  # holds controller functions
  end

  class Error < StandardError
  end
  class BadRequestError < Error
  end
end
```

Now that module is getting too big to keep it in one file so I want to split it up. As there are several classes in the module, I figured that every big class should be one file. So I didn't think a lot but tried to take out one class to see if it would work. Like so:

(file: zway.rb)

```
module Zway
  class API
  # instantiates API object
  end

  class Controller
  # holds controller functions
  end

  class Error < StandardError
  end
  class BadRequestError < Error
  end
end
```

(file: main.rb)

```
module Zway
  class Main
  end
end
```

But now I am getting this error which doesn't sound right to me as I do exactly what the error complains about: defining class Main in main.rb :

```
Unable to autoload constant Main, expected /bla/homer/app/models/main.rb to define it
```

I've searched on the net how to use modules but mostly what I found was about multiple inheritance and namespacing. But not about the practics of using modules to organize code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put your classes in modules, as per convention you should define them within folders named with the module_name. That's the whole point of organising. You can do something like this and give it a go. First organize your code and file like this ->

```
models/
  zway/
    main.rb
  zway.rb
```

And inside your main.rb you namespace it like this ->

```
class Zway::Main
  ...
end
```

and inside your zway.rb you define the module

```
module Zway
  ...
end
```

In this way, when you're trying to access the main class it, since its namespaced, it will look it up inside a folder `zway` by convention. And all your models are organized neatly within their respective folders.

Comment: For what it's worth, you may want to save yourself a headache down the road and use `module Zway; class Main` (nested) rather than `class Zway::Main` -- the two produce different results when it comes to namespace lookup, and the former is usually what you'd expect. Explored more thoroughly [here](http://randycoulman.com//blog/2014/12/09/namespaced-classes-in-rails/)